# How to uninstall RethinkDB on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstallation, rethinkdb

I'm having some issues with my RethinkDB server, I believe I have a memory leak that ended up filling my complete disk in a few days. As a result, I cannot even start the service! I get the following message when I try to run `rethinkdb` in the terminal:

```
Could not create directory 'rethinkdb_data': No space left on device
```

My first approach is to uninstall rethinkdb and remove all data (I don't really mind losing it). But there's no documentation on it... Any suggestions? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 on a virtual machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer is**, by default RethinkDB stores data in the `/root/rethinkdb_data` directory, so you should start there and blow away your data (if of course that you're okay with deleting it).

**The longer answer is**, you might not want to do that and delete other things so you have some disk wiggle space to fix the problem.

One of my favorite command line tools is [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) which allows you to see how much space the folders in the specified directory are taking up.

By default it will show you the size of the folder all the way down the directory tree. But I usually only care about the folders in the immediate folder so I can drill down deeper as needed.

This command will show you the size of the folders (but not files) in the current directory.

`du -h -d1 .`

This will still work even though your disk is out of space and allow you to identify which folders are taking up space. You may also notice that things like autocompletion in the terminal does not work when you are out of space, so try to resist pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Let me know if you're having more issues! [@dalanmiller](https://twitter.com/dalanmiller)

Comment: you saved the day today! I found that the .log file from my service in the upstart folder was **huge**: 50GB+!! I didn't even have to delete the data, Thank you very much